# What is the appropriate madvise setting for reading a file backwards?

Tags: c++, c++11, mmap

I am using gcc 4.7.2 on a 64-bit Linux box.

I have 20 large sorted binary POD files that I need to read as a part of the final merge in an external merge-sort.

Normally, I would `mmap` all the files for reading and use a `multiset<T,LessThan>` to manage the merge sort from small to large, before doing a `mmap` write out to disk.

However, I realised that if I keep a `std::mutex` on each of these files, I can create a second thread which reads the file backwards, and sort from large to small at the same time.  If I decide, beforehand, that the first thread will take exactly n/2 elements and the second thread will take the rest, I will have no need for a mutex on the output end of things.

Reading lock contentions, can be expected to occur, on average, maybe 1 in 20 in this particular case, so that's acceptable.

Now, here's my question.  In the first case, it is obvious that I should call `madvise` with `MADV_SEQUENTIAL`, **but I have no idea what I should do for the second case, where I'm reading the file backwards.**

I see no `MADV_REVERSE` in the man pages.  Should I use `MADV_NORMAL` or maybe don't call `madvise` at all?

Recall that an external sort is needed when the volume of data is so large that it will not fit into memory.  So we are left with a more complex algorithm to use disk as a temporary store.  Divide-and-conquer algorithms will usually involve breaking up the data, doing partial sorts, and then merging the partial sorts.

**My steps for an external merge-sort**

1. Take n=1 billion random numbers and break them into 20 shards of equal sizes.
2. Sort each shard individually from small to large, and write each out into its own file.
3. Open 40 mmap's, 2 for each file, one for going forward, one for going backwards, associate a mutex with each file.
4. Instantiate a `std::multiset<T,LessThan> buff_fwd;` for the forward thread and a `std::multiset<T,GreaterThan> buff_rev` for the reverse thread.  Some people prefer to use priority queues here, but essentially, and sort-on-insert container will work here.
5. I like to call the two buffers surface and rockbottom, representing the smallest and largest numbers not yet added to the final sort.
6. Add items from the shards until n/2 is used up, and flush the shards to one output file using mmap from beginning towards the middle, and from the end towards to middle in the other thread.  You can basically flush at will, but at least one should do it before either buffer uses up too much memory.

Comment: Why read from the back? Just start from the middle.

Comment: Are you sure that reading the file backwards gives you any benefit, given that you have to block either thread using a mutex?

Comment: Why do you need the multiset? Why not do the classic merge sort?

Comment: @MatsPetersson on average, there will be a 1 in 20 chance for contention - that's probably acceptable tradeoff for a possible 2x gain in speed (if locking/unlocking were cheap).

Comment: And if you don't get read conention on the disk! ;) Given my experiments with writing large files I did yesterday, I'd say disk I/O is quite slow, and you are most likely waiting for disk I/O to happen 99% of the time of your sort.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin It may seem that a 20-way merge is a possibility (doing a bunch of 2 ways is also possible, but may be costly), but when you consider the memory limits of what you are doing, you end up back at square one again.  Divide-and-conquer, and then trickling the shards back in appears to be standard procedure for an external sort.

Comment: I still don't see why multiset is needed here. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Parallel_processing

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin I didn't answer your comment: it's actually a mini-optimisation (a bit hard to explain in a comment).  Without some kind of self-sorting container, at the merge step, you need to find the smallest number out of the 20 shards every time a number is extracted (just the surface): that's expensive.  All this is a consequence of memory limitations and the way certain external merge sorts are designed.

Comment: @MatsPetersson that's a good point: a freakish, alternating reading from the head and tail of a large file causing repeated head repositioning will be a painfully slow thrashing.  Hopefully, there is enough smart-caching by modern HDDs and/or kernel code to prevent this, but the only way to know is to try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest:

```
MADV_RANDOM
```

To prevent useless read-ahead (which is in the wrong direction).

Comment: +1 this sounds better than `MADV_NORMAL` or do nothing... ...maybe I'll submit a feature request to add a `MADV_REVERSE`